# mysql result not displaying based on my query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table called `add_project`:

```
+------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
| project_id | user_id | project_status_id | project_name |
+------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
|          1 |       1 |                 3 | abc          |
|          2 |       1 |                 0 | def          |
|          3 |       1 |                 1 | xyz          |
|          4 |       1 |                 3 | lmn          |
|          5 |       1 |                 0 | trs          |
|          6 |       1 |                 3 | ght          |
+------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Here on this table admin add the new projects. The admin `user_id` is 1 so it is all common. `project_status_id` indicates the completion status of that project (0=new, 1=working, 3=completed).

And I have another table called `asign_project`:

```
+----------+------------+---------+
| asign_id | project_id | user_id |
+----------+------------+---------+
|        1 |          1 |       5 |
|        2 |          5 |       9 |
|        3 |          2 |       5 |
|        4 |          4 |       5 |
|        5 |          6 |       9 |
|        6 |          3 |       9 |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

Here on this table the admin assigns the project to different users.

Now what I want is to find how many completed projects each user has done. As you can see, `project_id(1,4)` has been completed by `user_id=5`.

So my question is how do I get that value?

Below is the query that I have written:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   asign_project, add_project
WHERE  asign_project.project_id = add_project.project_id 
   AND project_status_id='3' 
   AND user_id='5'
```

But it is showing:

> `#1052 - Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous`

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f8e3b/1).

Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Do you have the column user_id both in the table asign_project and add_project?

Comment: Since `add_project.user_id` will necessarily always be 1, what is the point in having that column in that table?

Answer (score 1):

I guess both tables have `user_id` column, so you will need to more specify at table name.

```
Select 
    * 
FROM 
    asign_project, add_project 
WHERE 
    asign_project.project_id = add_project.project_id 
AND 
    project_status_id='3' 
AND 
    asign_project.user_id='5';
```

Answer (score 1):

the user_id belong to what table? you should add 
`TABLE_XXX.user_id.`

```
  Select * FROM asign_project, add_project 
       WHERE 
          asign_project.project_id = add_project.project_id 
       AND 
          project_status_id='3' 
       AND 
          asign_project.user_id='5';
```

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the two tables your select from have the same column name.

In your `WHERE` clause you just need to specify which tablename you want to use to get filter the data.

Example:

```
Select * 
FROM 
   asign_project, add_project 
WHERE 
   asign_project.project_id = add_project.project_id 
AND 
  asign_project.project_status_id='3' 
AND
  asign_project.user_id='5'
```

All that's been done is to replace `user_id` in your WHERE clause with `assign_project.user_id` (assuming that assign_project is the correct table you want to use)

Comment: @futuring as your new to SO it's good to select the tick next to the answer that solved your problem and upvote if you want.

Answer (score 0):

used this

**Replace user_id with add_project.user_id**

```
Select 
  * 
FROM 
  asign_project, add_project 
WHERE 
    asign_project.project_id = add_project.project_id 
AND 
    project_status_id='3' 
AND 
    add_project.user_id='5'
```